# How to organize a rails app using nosql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aerospike, filetree, nosql

I'm trying to create a Ruby on Rails app and I have recently started using NoSQL databases to store the data. However, I'm not sure how to organize the database files within the file tree. For instance, is the code for NoSQL only supposed to be put in the context of regular code files or can it have it's own folder for NoSQL database files?

Answer (score 2):

Whether your are using SQL or NoSQL databases, the design pattern of Rails won't change. Rails uses MVC and the M part which stands for model is the layer that interacts with the database.

In short, don't create another folder for NoSQL database files, they are all models so they should go in `models` folder.

Comment: Would the nosql sequences be written in the form of methods? I have never used nosql.